# Guava preconditions checkNull, checkArgument

Tags: java, guava

I want to check preconditions on a base class so that I know subtypes will always use constructor arguments that are valid.

Let's take as an example a constructor that:

1. takes 2 or more parameters
2. takes parameters of different types
3. for one parameter, it performs multiple checks (e.g. String is not null *and* not empty)

How would one best use the Guava preconditions approach in that case?

In a mock example like this: (this is contrived!)

```
protected AbstractException(String errorMessage, Throwable errorCause) {
  super(errorMessage, errorCause);
  checkNotNull(errorMessage,
      ErrorMessage.MethodArgument.CANNOT_BE_NULL_CHECK, "errorMessage");
  checkArgument(!errorMessage.isEmpty(),
      ErrorMessage.MethodArgument.CANNOT_BE_EMPTY_STRING_CHECK,
      "errorMessage");
  checkNotNull(errorCause, ErrorMessage.MethodArgument.CANNOT_BE_NULL_CHECK,
      "errorCause");
}
```

I end up calling `super` before checking the arguments because a call to `super` needs to be the first line of the method and, although I could do `super(checkNoNull(errorMessage))`, I cannot do the same wrapping using `checkArgument` because that returns `void`. So the dilemma is:

- Where do I put the checks on all arguments? I don't want to create a Builder just for that
- How do I "group" checks as in a fictitious `checkStringNotNullAndNotEmpty()`
- Should I rather think about integration with matchers frameworks? (hamcrest, fest assertions...)

I use the odd-looking ErrorMessage.MethodArgument.CANNOT_BE_NULL_CHECK because the default `throw` does not include an error message so from the testing side I cannot recognise this as an argument validation failure rather than a "any" NPE?

Am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but throwing an exception from other exceptions' constructor is a bad idea...

Comment: Agree. I did say "contrived". Incidentally, if you had a framework which only wanted to see Exceptions being tossed about with an error message set, what would you do? In this example I am redefining a upper bound base which requires messages..

Comment: Let's flip the question: what will you do if `Exception` discovers incorrect constructor arguments? You cannot throw validation exception, as this will discard the original problem that caused you to throw the first exception...

Comment: If a user of the framework tries to throw a framework exception, subclass of `AbstractException` that is, with an insufficiently descriptive error message (e.g. null, "", ...) than the framework throws on the attempt of creating the exception to protect a framework precondition (i.e. all exceptions can be logged because they have a message, can be filtered... an example of filtering is the fact that I require a non-null check to say it is one: ErrorMessage.MethodArgument.CANNOT_BE_NULL_CHECK)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been a comment, but it's too long.

- Calling `super` before the test is harmless provided that the super ctor doesn't do things which *it shouldn't do anyway*.
- It could be prevented via a static builder method, you need no Builder. But it's not worth it.
- I doubt that grouping tests is *generally* useful; if it was, then there would be a such method already. But if you need one such a concrete thing more than twice, then write your own; if it comes often, report it to the Guava team as an RFE.
- I'm pretty sure, matchers are an overkill here as you're just creating an exception, i.e., something used only rarely (I hope). As your test is runtime only, it *can't really help* to catch errors. It would be nice, if you could statically ensure a "properly" constructed exception, but it's impossible in pure java.

More important: The exceptions you're throwing are probably inferior to the ones you'd get without all the checks. Imagine the user provides a cause and no message. That's bad, you think, but you replace it with an NPE lacking any cause. That's worse.

Look at Guava's `Preconditions.format` (package private). They could check the correct number of arguments first, but they do not. You can provide too few or too many, which is an error, but ignoring it is the best way to handle it.

Comment: A user should not create an exception with a cause and no message, that's what I am trying to establish as a contract within the confines of the framework...

Comment: I know... but 1. you can't prevent them from doing so (maybe via something like FindBugs you could; maybe physical threat would do). 2. when they do, you can't make it any better, only worse (with your exception you lost the massage *and* the cause *and* the original exception type). 3. if you want to provide the cause, you can't use `Preconditions` but must run your own.